# Run an action by name in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ide

As much as I like to remember as many keyboard shortcuts as possible, there's always something I don't know how to do via a keyboard shortcut. Is there an Eclipse equivalent to <kbd>M-x</kbd> from [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) or *Find action by name* from [Intellij IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+L</kbd> which is the shortcut for **Show Key Assist**.

I use <kbd>Ctrl+3</kbd> a lot, which is the shortcut for **quick access** popup, where you can type the name of any view, perspective or open editor to open/switch to that, or the name of an action to run it. By the way, you can see if your choose have a shortcut assigned when selecting.

*Note:* this is on Ubuntu, may be slightly different on a Mac.

Comment: Quick Access is what I was thinking :)

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try Quick Assist by pressing Ctrl+3